# Python- New Variable inidcator

Tags: python, numpy

So I want to make new indicator variable to my dataframe (df), 
Basically i want it to read "Splits" unless another field (AssetClass) is "Future" in which case i want the new indicator to read "NotSplit"
the code im using at the moment is:

```
df['Category'] = 'Split'
df[df.AssetClass == "Future"].Category = 'NotSplit'
```

but so far it just seems to make the new variable and call it all "Split" and then skip over the next line. 
Can anyone see any problems here?

Comment: You are mixing attribute access (`object.attribute`) and item access (`object['item']`). These two are distinct. Please clarify your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
df['Category'] = 'NotSplit' if df.AssetClass == 'Future' else 'Split'
```

Some background: currently you will get a new key in your dict (either `True` or `False`) because the result of the `df.AssetClass == 'Future'` evaluation is used. On other words, you get the following:

```
df['Category'] = 'Split'
df[True] = 'NotSplit'
```

If you just want to update the entry, reuse the same key name.

The above solution in multiple lines comes down to the following:

```
df['Category'] = 'Split'
if df.AssetClass == 'Future':
    df['Category'] = 'NotSplit'
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but both give me an error: "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: That error message seems to have no relation with the problem for which you asked the question. Could you verify that the code snippet I posted (just that part) works without errors? If so, I'd recommend that you post a new question for the next problem you are facing to keep things to the point.

Comment: yes its numpy array. not quite sure why i am getting this error, is it something to do with the array of the df that i have?

Comment: I have a feeling that i am not able to do an if condition on an array?